# Is "undecidable" can be represented in ASP (Answer Set Programming)?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

A sentence like

```
If a(X), then one can't decide/conclude anything about a(X) being b(X)
```

First attempt

```
b(X) | -b(X) :- a(X).
```

Second attempt

```
:- a(X), b(X).
:- a(X), -b(X).
```

First one makes no change to the solution while second one makes everything unsatisfiable.

Answer (score 1):

After a long meditation, I will answer my own question...

One way to translate the sentence is

```
b(X) :- a(X), not -b(X).
-b(X) :- a(X), not b(X).
```